# Stubbing Fetch Call - response.json will not invoke

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon, sinon-chai, proxyquire

I am trying to stub a fetch call with sinon and `sinon-stub-promise`. I'm pretty close...but I am not sure why it doesn't invoke the `response.json()` method I created.

```
function toJSON(response) {
  console.log(response);       
  return response.json();
}

function init() {
  fetch(darkWeatherUrl)
    .then(toJSON)
    .then(computeHours)
    .then(sendAlerts)
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log('init error ' + e);
    });
}
```

---

```
describe('lifx alert test', ()=> {

  it('should run fetch', ()=> {

    var fetch = sinon.stub().returnsPromise();

    var body = {
      "hourly": {
         data:
           [ { time: 1493413200,
              icon: 'clear-day',
              precipIntensity: 0,
              precipProbability: 0,
              ozone: 297.17 },
            { time: 1493416800,
              icon: 'clear-day',
              precipIntensity: 0,
              precipProbability: 0,
              ozone: 296.89 },
            { time: 1493420400,
              icon: 'clear-day',
              precipIntensity: 0,
              precipProbability: 0,
              ozone: 296.73 },
            { time: 1493424000,
              icon: 'clear-day',
              precipIntensity: 0,
              precipProbability: 0,
              ozone: 296.31 } ]
        }
    };


    function json() {
      return body;
    }

    var response = {};

    response.json = json;


    fetch.resolves(response);
    var init =  proxy('../index.js', {'node-fetch': fetch});
    init();
    fetch.should.have.been.called;
  });

});
```

---

```
 lifex alert test
{ json: [Function: json] }
[ { time: 1493413200,
    icon: 'clear-day',
    precipIntensity: 0,
    precipProbability: 0,
    ozone: 297.17 },
  { time: 1493416800,
    icon: 'clear-day',
    precipIntensity: 0,
    precipProbability: 0,
    ozone: 296.89 },
  { time: 1493420400,
    icon: 'clear-day',
    precipIntensity: 0,
    precipProbability: 0,
    ozone: 296.73 },
  { time: 1493424000,
    icon: 'clear-day',
    precipIntensity: 0,
    precipProbability: 0,
    ozone: 296.31 } ]
init error TypeError: response.json is not a function
    â should run fetch


  1 passing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**See update on the bottom also**

I removed `sinon-stub-promise` and kept it native sinon:

```
describe('lifx alert test', ()=> {
  var fetchStub;

  beforeEach(() => {
    fetchStub = sinon.stub();
  });

  it('should run fetch', ()=> {

    var body = {
      "hourly": {
         data:
           [ { time: 1493413200,
              icon: 'clear-day',
              precipIntensity: 0,
              precipProbability: 0,
              ozone: 297.17 },
            { time: 1493416800,
              icon: 'clear-day',
              precipIntensity: 0,
              precipProbability: 0,
              ozone: 296.89 },
            { time: 1493420400,
              icon: 'clear-day',
              precipIntensity: 0,
              precipProbability: 0,
              ozone: 296.73 },
            { time: 1493424000,
              icon: 'clear-day',
              precipIntensity: 0,
              precipProbability: 0,
              ozone: 296.31 } ]
        }
    };


    var response = { json: () => { return body } };
    fetchStub.returns(Promise.resolve(response));
    var init =  proxy('../index.js', {'node-fetch': fetchStub});
    init();
    fetchStub.should.have.been.called;
  });
```

**UPDATE**

I got it to work with `sinon-stub-promise` with proxyquire's global attribute:

```
describe('lifx alert test', ()=> {

  it('should run fetch', ()=> {

    var fetch = sinon.stub().returnsPromise();

    var body = {
      "hourly": {
         data:
           [ { time: 1493413200,
              icon: 'clear-day',
              precipIntensity: 0,
              precipProbability: 0,
              ozone: 297.17 },
            { time: 1493416800,
              icon: 'clear-day',
              precipIntensity: 0,
              precipProbability: 0,
              ozone: 296.89 },
            { time: 1493420400,
              icon: 'clear-day',
              precipIntensity: 0,
              precipProbability: 0,
              ozone: 296.73 },
            { time: 1493424000,
              icon: 'clear-day',
              precipIntensity: 0,
              precipProbability: 50,
              ozone: 296.31 } ]
        }
    };


    var response = { json: () => { return body } };


    fetch['@global'] = true;
    fetch.resolves(response);
    proxy('../index.js', {'node-fetch': fetch});
    fetch.should.have.callCount(3);
  });

});
```